# Grep $_SESSION['id'] only in php files

Tags: php, linux, grep, pattern-matching

Trying to grep `$_SESSION['id']` only in PHP files

```
grep -r --include="*.php" "SESSION\['id'\]" /var/www/ > grep.txt
```

But I got something terrible in `grep.txt` and not only matches.

How to write right syntax?

Comment: output is 180 Mb of garbage not only matching pattern just random php files

Comment: I would try it on a smaller directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$_` is being interpreted within double quotes: `grep "$var"` is looking for the content of `$var`, whereas `grep '$var'` is looking for the literal string `$var`.

So you need to use single quotes to avoid this. Since your pattern already contains single quotes, we have to close and open again:

```
'$_SESSION['"'"'id'"'"']'
```

All together:

```
grep -r --include="*.php" '$_SESSION['"'"'id'"'"']' /var/www/ > grep.txt
```

Ugly, I know.

Comment: Should I escape square brackets?

Comment: The same garbage not only matches

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin Where do you see this garbage? In `grep.txt` or in your screen? Update your question showing sample output

Comment: Yep everithing ok if i remove $_  `grep -Fr --include="*.php" "SESSION['id']" /var/www/ > grep.txt`, seem to `$_` makes another results

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin ok then the problem is with `$_` being interpreted as it is within double quotes. If you type `echo $_` you will see it has some values. So what we have to do is use single quotes: `'$_SESSION['"'"'id'"'"']'` should make it.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin nice! I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: To include a single quote in a single-quote delimited string just use `\047`, i.e. you can use `'$_SESSION[\047id\047]'` instead of `'$_SESSION['"'"'id'"'"']'` or you can just use double quotes and escape the `$` sign: `"\$_SESSION['id']"`. You'll also need to add `-F` is you aren't going to escape the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Wish I could find the guy who gave GNU grep options to search for files to ask why and who told him it was a reasonable thing to do!

Anyway... the UNIX tool to find files is named `find`:

```
find /var/www -name '*.php' | xargs grep -F "\$_SESSION['id']"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a command-line tool called '[ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/)'. By default, it only searches 'source code', but you can also narrow things down to specific file extensions (like `--php` which matches ".php .phpt .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml", and the #!  line with 'php' in it).

You can also set it to also ignore particular directories by default - I've set a local config to not go into the vendor/ directory.

```
ack --php "\$_SESSION['id']"
```

The `$` still has to be \quoted - though that's because of the external double-quotes.